# Software for home routers to block HTTPS website

Tags: home-networking, internet-security

I have a netgear R7000p and I am looking to block snapchat on the home router. Is there anything that could help me with this. I have tried to use OpenDNS and the website blocking functionality built into the router. However, HTTPS traffic is not stopped (I imagine the encryption hides the URL as well maybe?)

Help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Something like piHole might meet your needs.

Comment: ahh ok thanks, I was going to set that up to block ads network wide. Now I will get cracking.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS doesn't hide the hostname (first part of the URL), the destination IP address, or the DNS requests. Any of these are opportunities to block HTTPS traffic.

DNS blocking is the most typical. @Ramhound made a good recommendation for the piHole, which is a DNS based ad blocker.

Comment: So, I made a pi hole and set that up and it looks to be blocking as expected :) cheers

Comment: Please beware that HTTPS does NOT hide what is often the most sensitive part of most URLs. The server hostname (fully qualified domain name) is visible in cleartext in the TLS handshake. It's called the Server Name Indication (SNI), and is necessary due to the prevalence of virtual hosting. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication